# After how many iterations can I shortcut the Delina, Wild Mage / Pixie Guide combo?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-competitive-rel

I'm playing at competitive rules enforcement with [Delina, Wild Mage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Delina%2C%20Wild%20Mage) and [Pixie Guide](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pixie%20Guide). If I attack with [Delina, Wild Mage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Delina%2C%20Wild%20Mage) targeting [Pixie Guide](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pixie%20Guide) with the triggered ability, I'll continue creating copies of [Pixie Guide](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pixie%20Guide) for as long as I successfully roll `15—20`.

For my first roll, I'll roll two dice and ignore the lowest roll from the *Grant an Advantage* ability. If I succeed on that roll, I'll have an extra copy of [Pixie Guide](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pixie%20Guide) and roll again, but with three dice and ignoring the two lowest. As I continue to succeed, it will become more and more likely that I succeed:

| Iterations | Dice Rolled | Approx. Prob. Success | Approx. Aggregate P(Success) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 51% | 51% |
| 2 | 3 | 66% | 33% |
| 3 | 4 | 76% | 25% |
| 4 | 5 | 83% | 21% |
| 5 | 6 | 88% | 19% |
| 6 | 7 | 92% | 17% |
| 7 | 8 | 96% | 16% |

As I continue to succeed, the probability of success approaches 100%, but is never certain. At any point during the combo, I can choose to stop as [Delina, Wild Mage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Delina%2C%20Wild%20Mage) was errata'd to say "you may roll again".

Normally in Magic, once you demonstrate a loop, you can normally shortcut it by saying that you'd repeat the iteration until you reach a desired result. However, at each iteration, the probability of success is not guaranteed. Since the loop is non-deterministic, it seems like I shouldn't be able to shortcut it - I'm not able to definitively say where the game state will be after each iteration.

However, Toby Elliot (a level 5 judge who writes the Magic Tournament Rules and Infraction Procedure Guide for judges) spoke about the combo on Twitter saying:

> "Once you hit a certain point, your opponent probably just concedes, so the question is mostly moot.
>
> Beyond that, once you hit a point where the odds are basically 1, announce how many you’re making and stop. But your opponent already conceded."
>
> https://twitter.com/tobyelliott/status/1410662063228211206

It seems like at after a certain number of iterations, I *am* able to shortcut this combo, as long as the odds are "basically 1".

What is the number of iterations in which I can stop rolling handfuls of d20s and start shortcutting this combo to say something like "I make a number of [Pixie Guide](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pixie%20Guide)s equal to twice your life total"?

Comment: I would guess since it can fail and stop at any time you can't shortcut it at all.

Comment: @JoeW that's what I assumed too, but the person that writes the guidelines for tournament Magic play said in their tweet that you could shortcut it after a certain point

Comment: Maybe once you have 15 dice and the lowest you can roll is 15.

Comment: @JoeW Pixie Guide's ability doesn't add dice together, but rather makes you ignore the lowest results. There's a small chance during each iteration that you'll fail to roll 15 or above on every die you roll.

Comment: Well I am confused as it appears you are rolling an additional dice each time around as the success chance goes up.

Comment: Yes, you roll an additional die for each Pixie Guide, and ignore all but the greatest result. As the number of dice increases, the expected value of the greatest result increases.

Comment: Corollary question: At what point does executing this loop become Slow Play and/or Stalling?

Comment: @toroid I believe you roll three dice the first time since you copy the Pixie Guide before rerolling, and so on thereafter, ie your second column of numbers is off by one.

Comment: @DavidZ The first iteration is the first time I resolve Delina's ability - I don't have any copies of Pixie Guide yet beyond the original. The first iteration defines the loop, the second iteration repeats that loop.

Comment: @toroid Ah got it, I see what you mean.

Comment: I'd suggest that anyone running this kind of deck should have multiple d20s on hand so you can roll them all at once instead of one at a time.

Comment: Wow, so, the guy in the tweet is assuming that anyone would care about short-circuiting the die rolls after their opponent already conceded? With the assumption of already having the concession, that tweet becomes such a total non-answer that it makes me hope there's some way for players to downvote inane statements made by judges in public.

Comment: @nick012000 Pokemon judge, not MTG, but there's no reason it would be stalling.  Each action increases the chance of the player winning; and the other player is free to concede at any point.  If it's effectively 100%, then the other player *should* concede, unless they think they're advantaged by not doing so.

Comment: Every iteration is dependent on succeeding in the iterations before them, thus the probability of successfully completing the 2nd iteration (if you start from the beginning) would be .51*.66, the 3rd would be .51*.66*.76, etc. Your maths is only correct if you're already at the iteration directly before it. If you're at, say, the 4th iteration, there's only a 65% (.83*.88*.92*.96) chance that you'll get to the 8th iteration. So the probability that you'll actually keep going for particularly long (or indefinitely) is much lower than it appears with the probabilities in the question.

Comment: @JoeW If you role 1 die and need a 15 or higher, you have a 6 in 20 chance (30%). If you roll 2 dice and need one 15 or higher, you have a 6 in 20 chance for each, that works out to 30% for the first die, and 21% (30% of the 70% first die failure) for a total chance of 51%. A third die would be another 14.7% (30% of 49% chance the first two failed) for a total of 65.7% - there's always a chance every die will fail, but it gets less likely each cycle.

Comment: @Joe There are ways that an opponent could be advantaged by their opponent creating infinite tokens in magic, or at least not disadvantaged, even a few ways to win because of it ("quicken" spells like stronghold discipline or pact of the serpent). And if a mandatory effect like this does go on infinitely (if it had ever reached 100%) the rules do cover entering into a loop that neither player can break out of, it forces a draw.

Comment: @Andrew I fully understand that the chance of getting something goes up the more times you roll a die. What I didn't understand from the question is what exactly it meant by dice rolled. At first I was thinking it was total dice rolled and not number of times a die is rolled.

Comment: @nick012000 there is no slow play problems if you have demonstrated a loop you choose an arbitrary amount of iterations of the loop and the game continues. A thing that few MTG players realise is that you cannot go infinite in this game.

Comment: @NeilMeyer Except that in this case, you don't choose an arbitrary amount of iterations - if you want to execute the loop 100 times, you need to actually execute the loop 100 times.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The statement in that tweet is not backed up by the rules. [Rule 722.2a](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Shortcut) describes how taking shortcuts works:

> At any point in the game, the player with priority may suggest a shortcut by describing a sequence of game choices, for all players, that may be legally taken based on the current game state and the predictable results of the sequence of choices. This sequence may be a non-repetitive series of choices, a loop that repeats a specified number of times, multiple loops, or nested loops, and may even cross multiple turns. **It can’t include conditional actions, where the outcome of a game event determines the next action a player takes.** The ending point of this sequence must be a place where a player has priority, though it need not be the player proposing the shortcut.

in addition, section 4.4 of the [Magic Tournament Rules](https://media.wpn.wizards.com/attachements/mtg_mtr_23jul21_en_0.pdf) includes a paragraph that says

> **Non-deterministic loops (loops that rely on decision trees, probability, or mathematical convergence) may not be
> shortcut.** A player attempting to execute a nondeterministic loop must stop if at any point during the process a
> previous game state (or one identical in all relevant ways) is reached again. This happens most often in loops that
> involve shuffling a library.

The shortcut described only works on the condition that you get the 15-20 effect every time your roll, so it is not allowed by those rules as written. I think it's worth noting that in the current Magic Tournament Rules, none of the predefined tournament shortcuts have any conditional actions.

It's not really clear how seriously that tweet is supposed to be taken. A [later tweet](https://twitter.com/tobyelliott/status/1410662063228211206) by the same person in the same thread, in response to one asking where the cutoff is for rounding up to 1, says

> It’s the point after which your opponent has conceded, so we never actually have to get into the math.

I think you could easily read this as saying that you can never actually take the described shortcut, because it's only possible after the game is already over.

Mathematically, there is no independently defined cutoff where one number is "basically 1" and another isn't. Of course, it is possible to define a cutoff such as "whenever the probability of failing to get the desired number of consecutive successes is <1%", but until the Magic rules provide such a cutoff, there's no consistent way to resolve this.

Comment: I forget what the combo was, but many years back there was a combo deck in legacy that had similar issues. People would demonstrate a loop that theoretically allowed them to stack their deck to an exact sequence and then stack their deck in the desired way. The problem was that the chance of this exact sequence occurring wasn't 1. As I remember people were no longer allowed to stack their deck as desired without going through the motions, and going through the motions was prohibitively slow.

Comment: You might be thinking of "Four Horsemen", a combo in which players would try to mill a certain set of cards into their graveyard in a certain order, and if they failed, they would mill for an Emrakul, the Aeons Torn to start over. The problem with that combo as opposed to this one is that the probability of success never increased, so they never got any closer to winning. After each attempt, they either won, or were no better off than when they started.

Comment: If you can please see my answer and make a comment. I would appreciate a seasoned rules experts view on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The probability it stops when you have N pixies .7^N.  As .7 is very close to 1/sqrt(2), this means the probability of stopping is very close to 1 in 2^(N/2).

The probability of it *ever* stopping after pixie N is thus basically equal to the sum of i from N+1 to infinity of 1/2^(i/2).  As 1/2^((i+1)/2) is less than 1/2^(i/2), we can bound this above by the sum from (N+1)/2 to infinity of 2 * 1/2^i, which is simply 4 * 1/2^((N+1)/2), which is less than 4 / 2^(N/2).

So after 20 rolls, the odds you will *ever* fail are less than 0.4%.

This is depressingly slow.  I suspect most players won't concede if their chance of surviving is over 1%.  It is merely an upper bound; the actual value is going to be a touch lower, but not that much (under 25% difference, if my napkin math is correct).

The point where your chances of ever failing are under 1 in a million is after 40 pixies.  The point where your chances of ever failing are under 1 in a trillion are after 80 pixies.  The point where your chances of ever failing are under 1 in a googol is after 667 pixies.

Your opponent has probably conceded before you have 667 pixies.  But you'd probably stop making pixies before you hit 667 as well.

## TL;DR

The point, in number of Pixies, where you would reasonably be able to state "I am almost certainly able to make as many Pixies as I want" is almost always going to be at a point *after* you have enough Pixies to win.

There is no rule in MtG that translates "you are almost certainly going to be able to do X" into "you can do X".  However, in this case it is pretty much moot, because the rate at which *certainty* grows isn't really fast enough to matter much.

It is reasonable for the rules to allow your opponent to ask you to roll 13d20 and ensure you get a 15+ if you want another pixie, as that has a 1% chance of failure.

At 20 pixies, getting at 15+ roll has a 0.08% chance of failure, and the accumulated chance of a failure at any point in the future is more like 0.25%; a 1 in 400 chance.

MtG doesn't say "this is almost certain, you win" at any point, and even if it does it would probably be well after 20 pixies.

It is, however, possible that if the defending player has Graham's number life and insisted that you continue to roll d20s to spawn more pixies after you have 100 of them.  If this ever happens, I suspect the judge's decision will be scrutinized heavily.

"Unsporting conduct -- Stalling" may be appropriate here.  The player with the infinite pixie combination is almost certainly going to win, and the decision not to concede and require the (near infinite) dice to be rolled (with a near zero chance of failure) is almost entirely aimed at running the round time out.  This is going to be a strange case, because the player doing the actions is not the one possibly stalling.  "Stalling" is about intent to use the time constraint, not actions, and the *intent* of requiring all the dice to be rolled is "I am going to lose, but I tie if I make all the dice be rolled due to time constraints".

## A fair way to handle it

It isn't hard to calculate the cumulative chance of failure after having X pixies at any point from there to infinity.  Pre-calculating that would provide a "fair" way to handle the Graham's (or other insane life totals; 100 and Graham's number chance of failing is not practically different) cases.

If F_i is the chance of failure when rolling id20 for a 15+, then an upper bound on the chance of *ever* getting a failure after X pixies is sum i from X to infinity of F_i.

(This is actually the expected *total number* of failures, which is higher than the chance of ever failing).

F_i is .7^i, the sum is .7^(X) + .7^(X+1) + ..., which is .7^X * (1 + .7^2 + .7^3 + ...) which is .7^X * (1/1-.7), which is 3.33 * .7^X.

Which in turn is less than rolling Xd20 4 times and passing all 4 tries.

The actual chance of any failure is:
.7^X + (1-.7^X)*.7^(X+1) + (1-(1-.7^X)*.7^(X+1)) * .7^(X+2) + ...

When .7^X is almost 0, this is very close to the above calculation (it is off by a factor of less than (1-.7^X)).  3.333/4 < (1-.7^X) when X>=5; so this approximation is fair (gives an advantage to your opponent) if you have at least 5 pixies already.

So at any point in this combo, when you have X (5 or more) pixies, asking "I want to continue until I have a near infinite number of pixies.  The chance of failure is less than the chance of rolling Xd20 4 times and failing on any of the 4 rolls.  How about I just do that instead?"

That gives the defender a greater chance of you failing than doing it manually, and it takes far less time.  You, personally, choose to manually roll up to X pixies, where X is large enough that you feel comfortable with the advantage you are giving your opponent by not rolling forever.

(4 rolls seems unfair to say "I get to win an infinite number of rolls", but it works because each roll you *win* would make the chance of a later failure drop further; the improvement is so rapid that the 4 rolls without improvement is a fair handicap to match up against infinite rolls with improvement.)

Comment: Are you saying that at Competitive REL, you can or cannot use this shortcut? If you can, after how many iterations are you saying that the shortcut can be taken?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I am stating that the point where the shortcut is almost certainly going to work indefinitely is past the point where you have almost certainly already won.  So the point is moot; keep rolling until you have enough fairies to win.

Comment: Your answer seems to be assuming that the number of pixies needed to win is about 20. Does your answer change if it isn't? What if the opponent has gained 100 life? 1000? Also, I think there's an error in the last expression in your second paragraph. It looks like you're inverting the whole exponential expression, as compared to the previous expression. Or maybe the notation is just confusing.

Comment: In particular, what would be your answer if before you went off with your Pixie combo, I had gone off with my Spike Feeder / Heliod combo and gained [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) life?

Comment: "_The point where your chances of ever failing are under 1 in a **google** is after 667 pixies._" Did you mean a [Googol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol)?

Comment: @Tim yes I did.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Removed typo of `/ 1`.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I added a possible way a judge could rule based on "stalling", but who am I kidding, this would be unprecedented.  :)

Comment: I wonder if a call of stalling would be appropriate, since as you point out, the person stalling is not actually doing anything other than passing priority in a timely manner - they're not taking too long to do anything they should be doing, and they can't do anything to make the loop play out any faster by accepting a shortcut. Such a call would mean that players could be penalized for failing to concede in situations they're unlikely to win, but there's no threshold for how unlikely that should be before mandating that a player concede.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie The wording of "stalling" implies it isn't your actions, it is your motivations.  And if the other party offers a fair way to shorten the near-infinite set of dice rolls and actions, refusing it would be the stalling.  But, as I said, this would be both unprecedented, and extremely unlikely to ever occur in a serious match.  You'd need a near infinite-life combo that doesn't use it to win, which then comes up against this near-infinite pixie combo before it wins, and the near-infinite life player not accepting their loss.

Comment: @Yakk The problem is, the combo player has no option to offer a valid shortcut since there is no defined end state. Suppose you have X pixies and roll Xd20 to see if you can achieve "infinite" pixies, and *fail the roll* - the board state is now undefined, since it's impossible to say how many pixies you actually have. Your fair method is indeed pretty fair, but it's not a valid shortcut because it's conditional on the dice roll. I don't see any way the combo player can propose a valid shortcut, and if no proposal is made, the non-combo player can't stall by rejecting it.

Comment: Basically, rejecting a valid shortcut would be stalling. Rejecting a series of actions intended to approximate actual gameplay in a manner explicitly disallowed by the rules wouldn't be. The suggested "shortcut" is invalid can't be legally proposed or accepted. Unless the combo player proposed a *valid* shortcut, there's literally nothing the non-combo player can do within the rules to make the combo play out any faster.

Comment: Your proposed solution of rolling some finite number of dice to simulate all future rolls is probably not legal. The tournament rules (section 5.2) say "The result of a match or game may not be randomly or arbitrarily determined through any means other than the
normal progress of the game in play. Examples include (but are not limited to) rolling a die..." Since you are suggesting rolling those dice in lieu of taking the actual game actions, doing so may be in violation of the tournament rules

Comment: I also want to add my voice pushing back on the claim that it is "stalling" if the opponent does not concede. I have never seen an official ruling that requires someone to concede the game, and I do not believe it would ever be a fair requirement. The basic principle here is that if a player chooses to play a slow, non-deterministic combo, the responsibility for finishing the combo in a timely manner lies with that player, and it would be unfair to punish their opponent for making them play by the rules. This is why you lose instead of winning for running out your clock in MTGO.

Comment: Related discussion on why a different but similar combo is stalling: https://magicjudge.tumblr.com/post/152521707334/why-isnt-the-four-horsemen-combo-a-loop-like-why

Comment: A critical difference between this combo and four horsemen is that in this combo, every roll either ends the combo in failure, or makes meaningful progress towards ending the combo in success. On the other hand, in the four horsemen combo, every iteration either wins the game immediately, or resets to the original state, no closer to winning. That reset disallows the combo under the loop rules I quoted in my own answer. There is also a big difference between calling a combo stalling because it makes no progress, and saying that the opponent is stalling for not conceding to the combo.

Comment: Stalling requires both an intent to run out the clock as well as actions to serve that intent. You can't penalize someone for stalling simply because they'd *like* to run out the clock if they haven't taken any action to do so. The non-combo player can take no action whatsoever to run out the clock - they can't accept an illegal shortcut or a "replacement" die roll to speed things up. Literally all they can do is pass priority, but you're suggesting they could be penalized if they don't accept an illegal shortcut or some other illegal approximation of gameplay.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the infinite series approach and just build a table for the expected number of Pixie Guide Tokens, then map that to a roll of permillenial dice (6 d10s read as digits of a number from 000000-999999, with all zeroes being read as 1,000,000). For fairness, you'll end up reducing your token in count in some cases so as to never have a case where your odds for a given "token count or more" are increased:

(The table for the odds used to calculate the roll follows the first table)

Perhaps the judge will be familiar enough with infinite series to allow this as the shortcut.

| Roll | Tokens |
| --- | --- |
| 1-490,000 | 1 |
| 490,001-664,930 | 2 |
| 664,931-745,380 | 3 |
| 745,381-788,173 | 4 |
| 788,174-813,094 | 5 |
| 813,095-828,486 | 6 |
| 828,487-838,373 | 7 |
| 838,374-844,895 | 8 |
| 844,896-849,276 | 9 |
| 849,277-852,256 | 10 |
| 852,257-854,300 | 11 |
| 854,301-855,711 | 12 |
| 855,712-856,689 | 13 |
| 856,690-857,369 | 14 |
| 857,370-857,842 | 15 |
| 857,843-858,172 | 16 |
| 858,173-858,402 | 17 |
| 858,403-858,563 | 18 |
| 858,564-858,675 | 19 |
| 858,676-858,753 | 20 |
| 858,754-858,808 | 21 |
| 858,809-858,846 | 22 |
| 858,847-858,873 | 23 |
| 858,874-858,891 | 24 |
| 858,892-858,904 | 25 |
| 858,905-858,913 | 26 |
| 858,914-858,919 | 27 |
| 858,920-858,923 | 28 |
| 858,924-858,926 | 29 |
| 858,927-858,928 | 30 |
| 858,929-858,929 | 31 |
| 858,930-858,930 | 32 |
| 858,931-858,931 | 33 |
| 858,932-858,932 | 34 |
| 858,933-858,933 | 35 |
| 858,934-858,934 | 36 |
| 858,935-858,935 | 37 |
| 858,936-858,936 | 38 |
| 858,937-858,937 | 39 |
| 858,938-858,938 | 40 |
| 858,939-858,939 | 41 |
| 858,940-858,940 | 42 |
| 858,941-858,941 | 43 |
| 858,942-858,942 | 44 |
| 858,943-858,943 | 45 |
| 858,944-858,944 | 46 |
| 858,945-858,945 | 47 |
| 858,946-858,946 | 48 |
| 858,947-1,000,000 | Infinity |

Calculation table:

| N | Dice | Success | Aggregate Success | Odds for N | Odds of "N or More" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0.51 | 0.51 | 49.0000% | 100% |
| 2 | 3 | 0.657 | 0.33507 | 17.4930% | 51.00000000% |
| 3 | 4 | 0.7599 | 0.254619693 | 8.0450% | 33.50700000% |
| 4 | 5 | 0.83193 | 0.211825761 | 4.2794% | 25.46196930% |
| 5 | 6 | 0.882351 | 0.186904672 | 2.4921% | 21.18257612% |
| 6 | 7 | 0.9176457 | 0.171512269 | 1.5392% | 18.69046722% |
| 7 | 8 | 0.94235199 | 0.161624928 | 0.9887% | 17.15122688% |
| 8 | 9 | 0.959646393 | 0.155102779 | 0.6522% | 16.16249278% |
| 9 | 10 | 0.971752475 | 0.150721509 | 0.4381% | 15.51027790% |
| 10 | 11 | 0.980226733 | 0.147741253 | 0.2980% | 15.07215094% |
| 11 | 12 | 0.986158713 | 0.145696324 | 0.2045% | 14.77412526% |
| 12 | 13 | 0.990311099 | 0.144284686 | 0.1412% | 14.56963235% |
| 13 | 14 | 0.993217769 | 0.143306114 | 0.0979% | 14.42846863% |
| 14 | 15 | 0.995252438 | 0.14262576 | 0.0680% | 14.33061142% |
| 15 | 16 | 0.996676707 | 0.142151772 | 0.0474% | 14.26257597% |
| 16 | 17 | 0.997673695 | 0.141821084 | 0.0331% | 14.21517725% |
| 17 | 18 | 0.998371586 | 0.141590141 | 0.0231% | 14.18210841% |
| 18 | 19 | 0.99886011 | 0.141428744 | 0.0161% | 14.15901407% |
| 19 | 20 | 0.999202077 | 0.141315894 | 0.0113% | 14.14287436% |
| 20 | 21 | 0.999441454 | 0.141236963 | 0.0079% | 14.13158944% |
| 21 | 22 | 0.999609018 | 0.141181742 | 0.0055% | 14.12369629% |
| 22 | 23 | 0.999726313 | 0.141143102 | 0.0039% | 14.11817418% |
| 23 | 24 | 0.999808419 | 0.141116062 | 0.0027% | 14.11431021% |
| 24 | 25 | 0.999865893 | 0.141097137 | 0.0019% | 14.11160618% |
| 25 | 26 | 0.999906125 | 0.141083892 | 0.0013% | 14.10971371% |
| 26 | 27 | 0.999934288 | 0.141074621 | 0.0009% | 14.10838917% |
| 27 | 28 | 0.999954001 | 0.141068131 | 0.0006% | 14.10746207% |
| 28 | 29 | 0.999967801 | 0.141063589 | 0.0005% | 14.10681315% |
| 29 | 30 | 0.999977461 | 0.14106041 | 0.0003% | 14.10635892% |
| 30 | 31 | 0.999984222 | 0.141058184 | 0.0002% | 14.10604097% |
| 31 | 32 | 0.999988956 | 0.141056626 | 0.0002% | 14.10581842% |
| 32 | 33 | 0.999992269 | 0.141055536 | 0.0001% | 14.10566263% |
| 33 | 34 | 0.999994588 | 0.141054772 | 0.0001% | 14.10555358% |
| 34 | 35 | 0.999996212 | 0.141054238 | 0.0001% | 14.10547724% |
| 35 | 36 | 0.999997348 | 0.141053864 | 0.0000% | 14.10542381% |
| 36 | 37 | 0.999998144 | 0.141053602 | 0.0000% | 14.10538640% |
| 37 | 38 | 0.999998701 | 0.141053419 | 0.0000% | 14.10536022% |
| 38 | 39 | 0.99999909 | 0.141053291 | 0.0000% | 14.10534189% |
| 39 | 40 | 0.999999363 | 0.141053201 | 0.0000% | 14.10532906% |
| 40 | 41 | 0.999999554 | 0.141053138 | 0.0000% | 14.10532008% |
| 41 | 42 | 0.999999688 | 0.141053094 | 0.0000% | 14.10531380% |
| 42 | 43 | 0.999999782 | 0.141053063 | 0.0000% | 14.10530940% |
| 43 | 44 | 0.999999847 | 0.141053042 | 0.0000% | 14.10530632% |
| 44 | 45 | 0.999999893 | 0.141053027 | 0.0000% | 14.10530416% |
| 45 | 46 | 0.999999925 | 0.141053016 | 0.0000% | 14.10530265% |
| 46 | 47 | 0.999999948 | 0.141053009 | 0.0000% | 14.10530159% |
| 47 | 48 | 0.999999963 | 0.141053003 | 0.0000% | 14.10530085% |
| 48 | 49 | 0.999999974 | 0.141053 | 0.0000% | 14.10530034% |
| 49 | 50 | 0.999999982 | 0.141052997 | 0.0000% | 14.10529997% |
| 50 | 51 | 0.999999987 | 0.141052995 | 0.0000% | 14.10529972% |
| 51 | 52 | 0.999999991 | 0.141052994 | 0.0000% | 14.10529954% |
| 52 | 53 | 0.999999994 | 0.141052993 | 0.0000% | 14.10529942% |
| 53 | 54 | 0.999999996 | 0.141052993 | 0.0000% | 14.10529933% |
| 54 | 55 | 0.999999997 | 0.141052992 | 0.0000% | 14.10529927% |
| 55 | 56 | 0.999999998 | 0.141052992 | 0.0000% | 14.10529923% |
| 56 | 57 | 0.999999999 | 0.141052992 | 0.0000% | 14.10529920% |
| 57 | 58 | 0.999999999 | 0.141052992 | 0.0000% | 14.10529918% |
| 58 | 59 | 0.999999999 | 0.141052992 | 0.0000% | 14.10529916% |
| 59 | 60 | 0.999999999 | 0.141052991 | 0.0000% | 14.10529915% |
| 60 | 61 | 1 | 0.141052991 | 0.0000% | 14.10529914% |

(At this point, any result N>60 has the same results as N=60.)

Comment: Listing probabilities as 0 and 1 when they are not actually 0 and 1 is misleading, because a probability of 1 has a very different meaning than a probability of "very nearly 1" when talking about deterministic vs nondeterministic processes. I suggest instead "10^-n" and "1-10^-n" to show how close they actually are to 0 or 1.

Comment: Also, as I posted on the other answer, your proposed solution of rolling some finite number of dice to simulate all future rolls is probably not legal. The tournament rules (section 5.2) say "The result of a match or game may not be randomly or arbitrarily determined through any means other than the normal progress of the game in play. Examples include (but are not limited to) rolling a die..." Since you are suggesting rolling those dice in lieu of taking the actual game actions, doing so may be in violation of the tournament rules

Comment: Well, I did say "familiar enough with infinite series", which should cover any confusion about the rounding. If the rounding trips them up, this approach is destined to fail anyhow.

Comment: I'm not talking about judges. I am talking about what you are communicating to the reader of this answer.

Comment: Judges would not allow this as a shortcut no matter how familiar they are with the mathematics involved. The rules for shortcuts simply don't allow for it. We've seen plenty of precedent in decks that use infinite random events, like Four Horsemen. Even though their outcome is virtually guaranteed eventually, judges do not allow the random events to be shortcut past and require them to be played out. Players are only granted shortcuts for deterministic sequences shortcuts, like infinite scry 2 to rearrange a deck arbitrarily. [Read more here](https://apps.magicjudges.org/forum/topic/20489/)

Comment: For official tournaments this may not work, but for kitchen table, this is excellent!

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson, I assume you used double precision arithmetic to compute these results?

Comment: @John The question is about Competitive REL. Kitchen table is out of scope for answers.

Comment: @John double precision, yes. The tables are created in MS Excel, which uses IEEE 754 double precision.